Is there a term for encoder-decoder models with 0 layer encoder?
What do we call an encoder-decoder with 0 encoder layers and the cross-attention of decoder layers are directed to the outputs of the encoder embedding layer?

0-N Enc-decoder
Decoder-only with cross-attention
Prefix-LM
Decoder-only
Others

